# Pick random key based on weight and picked times

Tags: algorithm, random

I am designing an advertising system that rotates randomly between ads depending on their weight (bid).

```
local ads = local ads = {
    ["a"] = {
        views = 0,
        bid = 10
    },
    ["b"] = {
        views = 0,
        bid = 1000
    },
    ["c"] = {
        views = 0,
        bid = 100
    },
    ["d"] = {
        views = 0,
        bid = 50
    },
    ["e"] = {
        views = 0,
        bid = 500
    },
    ["f"] = {
        views = 0,
        bid = 10
    },
}
```

I searched around and found the following algorithm:

> 1. Get sum of all weighted numbers
> 2. Pick a random number between 0 and sum
> 3. Loop through table (ads) and if (random number) <= weight then return ad else random number = random number - weight

Using the algorithm and looping 1,000 times prints out

```
a 3
c 60
b 581
e 313
d 35
f 8
```

which is pretty okay. But as you can see ad f has received almost 3 times as much views ad a, even with equal weight (bid).

I tried to make the algorithm more fair by also taking into account the views the ad already got. I did this by reducing the weight with each view.

I couldn't make it work though and I wonder if someone can help me?

Comment: You should expect results to be uneven, especially for the low values. Run it for 1000000 and things will probably even out.

Comment: why the `python` tag?

Comment: @SQLHacks is correct. Based on Statistical Number Theory, lower numbers are more susceptible to the random number generator. Try looking for a crypto-random generator, this is if you want it to be really random. If you do things like this with really high numbers your still going to get askew data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be sure that everyone gets exactly the right proportion you can use this algorithm - it takes a lot of memory:

- Fill an array of size `sum` with 10 a, 1000 b, 100 c ...
- Shuffle the array randomly
- Pick items from the array in sequence, starting from 0

When you run out of elements you can either start again using the same array or recreate the array. You'll need to recreate the array every time the weights change anyway.